# How to Map photos and texts

Tags: regex, mapreduce, hbase

Please Observe the google Doc below:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dw6mJW0VxHzD3_h86RgtZwmelBQE8tYGgi41jb1oz-o/edit

I am attempting to put the data into Hbase using either MapReduce or Importtsv. But my main problem is dealing with the photos. I would like to put the photos in a seperate column family. How do i go about selecting only the photos and importing them into HBase, given that the photos dont have nothing that it can be identified by...like a (text) name.

I thought about using Regex. But some of the districts are of different structure. for instance, "Arizona 1" vs. "Alaska at large".

I need to know how to **specifically** identify the photos, so they that can be distinguished and imported appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Having in mind the structure of the document mentioned above, this is the expression you need. It will match all image URLs and each image description.

```
<image\sxlink:href="(https:\/\/[^"\s]+)".*?<title><\/title><desc>(.+?)<\/desc><\/image>
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/uQ8tT8/1)

Usage in PHP:

```
$html = '<p>Members of our tim</p><image xlink:href="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/z3GK1MdYyLTo0Q0xLmawvcptIrK4qkQx7XJWUgTK_i6Psm22GBqZXBh-w0TeQ5xgKxckQOB2wHWySSIpNj3tXx65MPXmaxKjK4ye_Xu-wAUFKLVhvWFgIedtzxo" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none"><title></title><desc>Bradley Byrne.jpg</desc></image><h1>Some big title</h1><p>Something <span>more</span> here</p><image xlink:href="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/fWYh7qTWqu4_4oxAiNhmnMCmD6DScZ6bIvkF5nSFunU8NxKlBT1T-1J85MJCqghhbChFzoLi-p4ZFVDCA2DWWBP9Paagp9ZgshqnGK5CQQF6D7IoBGihcFZoOms" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none"><title></title><desc>Spencer Bachus 113th Congress.jpg</desc></image><h1>TITLE</h1><p>Testing, testing, testing</p><image xlink:href="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/VAHzM6OkdtxT61j9XSgTDKlpVi99WsFfzNAlvqmnpCi90XFs9aUNMfuCeeeQ3e26fykjveoxldHvv5jO1Bk9IeEmeU7DdGVAM1N9xXoB8tJTYBeTeFBxigXtT5s" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none"><title></title><desc>Kyrsten Sinema 113th Congress.jpg</desc></image><p>Last updated on 25th of July, 2014</p>';
$pattern = '/<image\sxlink:href="(https:\/\/[^"\s]+)".*?<title><\/title><desc>(.+?)<\/desc><\/image>/';
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $html, $matches)){
  $size_of_matches = count($matches[0]);
  for($i = 0; $i < $size_of_matches; $i++){
    echo $matches[1][$i] . " -> " . $matches[2][$i] . "<br />";
  }
}
```

Output:

```
https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/z3GK1MdYyLTo0Q0xLmawvcptIrK4qkQx7XJWUgTK_i6Psm22GBqZXBh-w0TeQ5xgKxckQOB2wHWySSIpNj3tXx65MPXmaxKjK4ye_Xu-wAUFKLVhvWFgIedtzxo -> Bradley Byrne.jpg
https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/fWYh7qTWqu4_4oxAiNhmnMCmD6DScZ6bIvkF5nSFunU8NxKlBT1T-1J85MJCqghhbChFzoLi-p4ZFVDCA2DWWBP9Paagp9ZgshqnGK5CQQF6D7IoBGihcFZoOms -> Spencer Bachus 113th Congress.jpg
https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/VAHzM6OkdtxT61j9XSgTDKlpVi99WsFfzNAlvqmnpCi90XFs9aUNMfuCeeeQ3e26fykjveoxldHvv5jO1Bk9IeEmeU7DdGVAM1N9xXoB8tJTYBeTeFBxigXtT5s -> Kyrsten Sinema 113th Congress.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not have experience with MapReduce or Importtsv, so I went about this a different way using c#. As hex494D49 pointed out, the images do have text associated with them. You just have to obtain that data from the document's source (i.e. right click-->View page source).

This [code](http://pastebin.com/xYMYfirk) reads in the document's source, makes an attempt to match the politician with an image file (based on the available information that was posted), and writes the results to a text file. The code has many examples of the c# flavor of regex. A sample of the output is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzlos.png).

Comment: You might want to consider posting the code, or at least parts of it, here, as links might go dead. :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The code is rather verbose, and this was my first time posting. :)